# Recommended way to access Session object from views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am storing "POCO" objects in the Session object. I need to access them from my views -strongly typed to use Intellisense.

I think my options are 1. ViewModel and 2. Singleton class. Do I have more options? How should I decide? Thank you.

Comment: You should clarify what your POCO's are.  All they mean is "Plain Old CLR Object".  They could be anything.

Comment: Hi -when I say POCO I mean containers only, no functionality. Is that correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this type of work in the controller.  Grab whatever you need from the session and then convert to ViewModels.